# Custom field type in flask-restplus API restricts to one type

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I built an API using Flask-RESTPlus. I tried to set up a field that has a custom type (required for one of the devices i'm interfacing). The type should be "string or int". It works, however when i view the Swagger output, the model for `Channel Parameter` only contains "name" and not the "value" entry:

```
{
  "name": "string"
}
```

I have tried setting `__schema_type__ = 'string'`, which shows the model almost correctly (it should say "string or integer"):

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "value": "string"
}
```

however, then the validation fails if i provide an integer as the input for `value`.

The API is rather large, however, here are the relevant parts of the code:

```py
from flask_restplus import fields

# ... api (namespace) is declared here
# ... ccreate, Initializer are imported

class StringOrInt(fields.Raw):
    __schema_type__ = None
    def format(self, value):
        return value
    def validate(self, value):
        return isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, str)

channel_param_model = ns.model('Channel Parameter', {
    'name': fields.String('Parameter name', required=True),
    'value': StringOrInt('Parameter value (string or integer)'),
})

# ... more code here ...

@api.route('/endpoint')
class SomeClass(Initializer):
    @api.expect(channel_param_model, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        """Create a new channel"""
        channel_creation_response = ccreate(ns.payload)
        return channel_creation_response
```

How can I ensure validation works (allows string and int inputs) and Swagger output displays model properly?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```html
class StringOrInt(fields.Raw):
    __schema_type__ = ['string', 'integer']
    __schema_example__ = 'string or integer'
```